# How to develop Front-end and Back-end with different layouts in Zend framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework

How to develop Front-end and Back-end with different layouts in Zend framework 2 ?

Comment: What do you mean with "back-end"?

Answer (score 1):

Create new .phtml file (eg. layout_frontend.phtml ) in the layout adresary(application/layouts/scripts). Then in the controller **init** function tell the controller to use another layout:

```
public function init()
{
   $this->_helper->layout->setLayout( 'layout_frontend' );
}
```

or if you want just specific action to use it, just place it into the action code:

```
public function layoutAction( )
{
   $this->_helper->layout->setLayout( 'layout_frontend' );
   /* you action code */
}
```

I hope this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Firs of all You have to make a separation of the module with fronted And backed.

You find this concept here With [dotkernel](http://www.dotkernel.com/) which is actual open Source project And yes it is built up on the zf1. oh yes the zf1 is quite bit older but you get a good concept from the dotkernel.

once you find the separation concept form the dotkernal i would like To suggest you to make a different module for the back end and frond end by enabling module in `application.config.php` in zf2 application directory.

and make all component to that individual module `front-end and back-end`

[zf-campus](https://github.com/zfcampus) for re-usable code which is contributed by the zend core team and open source contributor. for the layout rendering you can fine [EdpSubLayout](https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpSubLayout) which is quite more useful.

@vrkansagara on IRC,TWITTER AND GITHUB.